# CodeIgniter - how to query DB session?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

My CI sessions are stored in my database.

I have a native PHP script outside of CodeIgniter that needs some information that's in `userdata`. Is there a way for my to query the CI session table and figure out what the current user's session is? I think CI checks the user IP and the "first 120 characters of the browser data string." Those 2 pieced of data are available to that outside script, right? Can I query for those 2 fields and get an accurate result? Or is CI somehow aware of what the `session_id` is?

Alternatively, I thought I could could set a native session variable from CI containing the information I needed and try to access it in the outside PHP script. It didn't work.

I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code to integrate comet chat(an external app) with my CI user system:  you might need to modify it but you can get the gyst:

```
$decoded_ci_session = @unserialize(@stripslashes($_COOKIE['ci_session']));

$sql = "SELECT user_data FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."sessions WHERE session_id = '".$decoded_ci_session['session_id']."'";

$query = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$decoded_ci_session = @unserialize(@stripslashes($row[0]));
```

at the end $decoded_ci_session should contain all the userdata normally in `$this->session->userdata()`

Comment: Interestingly, I'm doing this a part of CometChat integration. You put the entire CI session in a cookie?

Comment: I just used the default settings for the ci db_session library.  I think its like the session_id and two other pieces of info.  But with the session id you can query the db and get the rest of the data using it as a key.  You can just var_dump($_COOKIE) in that integration file in cometchat and it should tell you whats in ci_session.